# Insert JSON data to a hover div, matching an employee

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

By now i looped a JSON data into the HTML table, i have a hover div (display:none) which appears when I hover on some employee listed from JSON. Now i need to match every employee and write data like id, name, department etc.. into that hover div. I have a static template ready and i need some simplest solution.

Thanks!

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "generated.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var employees = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        write(employees);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();


function write(arr) {
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td class=\"hoverKartX\" user_id=" + arr[i].id + ">" + arr[i].name + "</td><td>" + arr[i].position + "</td></tr>";;
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("employees").innerHTML = out;
}



$(function() {
  var moveLeft = 20;
  var moveDown = 10;
  // var moveRight = 10;

  $('.hoverKartX').hover(function(e) {
    $('.hoverKart').show();
    
  }, function() {
    $('.hoverKart').hide();
  });

  $('.hoverKartX').mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.hoverKart').css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    
    
    if ($('.hoverKart').position()['left'] + $('.hoverKart').width() > $(window).width()) {
        $('.hoverKart').css("left", $(window).width() - $(".hoverKart").width());
    };
    
    if ((e.pageY + moveDown + $(".hoverKart").height()) > ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
      $('.hoverKart').css("top", $(window).height() - $(".hoverKart").height() + $(window).scrollTop());
    }
});

});
```

```css
.hoverKart {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- hidden -->
<div class="hoverKart">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cardTop"><p>ID0001</p></div>
            <div class="imgHolder">
                <img class="employee" src="img/img.jpg" alt="employee image">
                <img class="eLogo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="eipix logo">
            </div>
            <div class="eInformation">
                <p class="eName">First name and last name</p>
                <p class="ePos">Department</p>
            <div class="eDep">
                <img src="img/icons-dep/5.png" alt="department logo">
            </div>
            <p class="eOp">Operations</p>
            <p class="eOp2">Address</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h3>Employers list</h3>
<div id="employees">
  <!-- content from loop -->
  
  <p class="hoverKartX"> TEST USER </p>
  
</div>

<script src="jq/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying `unique id` for each user element to identify which element is currently hovered.

Let me try to explain by steps.

- Provide an unique `id` for each looping element
- Get an `$(this).attr('id')` of currently hovered element
- Call a write function with the id which is hovered then compare it in loop and get only hovered data.
- Finally, write the things using `.html()` which you wants to `show()` and `hide()`

**HTML**

```
<div id="employees">
  <!-- content from loop -->
  <p class="hoverKartX" id="1"> TEST1 USER </p>
  <p class="hoverKartX" id="2"> TEST2 USER </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $('.hoverKartX').hover(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    write(id);
    $('.hoverKart').show();
  }, function() {
    $('.hoverKart').hide();
  });
```

Write Function

```
function write(id) {
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].id == id)
        {  
        out += "<tr><td class=\"hoverKartX\" user_id=" + arr[i].id + ">" + arr[i].name + "</td><td>" + arr[i].position + "</td></tr>";;
        }
    }
    out += "</table>";
    //Dynamically HTML changed every-time hovered
    $('.hoverKart').html(out);
}
```

FYI, this is just an example. You might need to change variable name as per your need.

Comment: I have a custom attribute "user_id=" + arr[i].id + ">".

Comment: What i need is a table with name and position of a workplace (which i have), and while on hover to display more information about user like image, address etc..

Comment: I assumed that the `table` is created with dynamically content for hovered element and that will be write to the `.hoverKart` that will be shown and hide.

Comment: Exactly! I looped the content into the table from JSON and hover will be more information about user in .hoverKart.

Comment: @Bojan So what's the problem now  ? Did you understand what I've explained above.

Comment: Yes, sorry for delay. Thanks!